# Suggestion for a good statistics book for computer scientists, in preparation of machine learning

Tags: statistics, books

We (a group of CS postdocs and Ph.D. students) are starting a shared reading of a machine learning book ("An Introduction to Statistical Learning", James, Witten, Hastie, Tibshirani).

Before diving into it, however, we felt the need to get some more solid background on simple and pure statistics. We would like to start from some statistics book, maybe from the first chapters, and then jump back into the machine learning one.

Which introductory, but sufficiently deep, statistics book can you suggest to start from?

Comment: You don't need any statistics. You need elementary probability theory.

Comment: I’m not sure whether I agree with you on this... but by the way, we already have enough (I hope) basics of probability theory. We want to learn statistics, specifically.

Comment: you can check the following book which covers basic statistics Essentials of Bio-Statistics: An overview with the help of Software
ISBN: 978-1723712074

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is suitable here.  We have some ambivalence about book recommendation questions.  Generally, to make them work well, what's needed is for you to articulate some specific requirements that we can use to objectively evaluate answers, that's more than just a survey or opinion poll.  Our format doesn't work well for opinion polls or inherently subjective questions.  Also, generally it works better to ask how to learn some specific topics (which might involve multiple books...), rather than to ask for a single book.  What topics do you want to learn?  (continued)

Comment: What criteria do you have for evaluating books?  What's your background?  What books have you already considered, and in what ways did they meet or fail to meet your needs?  Right now I don't see much in the way of criteria; "simple and pure" is subjective, "introductory, but sufficiently deep" is a bit subjective as well (how will we know what level of depth you consider sufficient?  sufficient for what?).  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1360/755 and https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1312/755.

Comment: @D.W. Well, sufficiently deep to understand machine learning topics, which are our final target. But I think I understand your point. No problem if the question gets closed.